# Is there any notation for representing a set of values in a vector ranging from minimum to maximum with incremental step size?

Tags: notation

I want to represent the following in set form: 
Let $\textbf{a}_{(l)}$ represent a vector of $N_a$ distinct attenuation values ranging from minimum value $a_{(l)}^{\min}$ to maximum value $a_{(l)}^{\max}$ with incremental step size of $\Delta a_{(l)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity of notation, I will call the min value $a$, max value $b$, and step size $h$. $$\{a+hk:  0\leq  k \leq ?,  k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

To solve for ?, we want to solve $a+?h = b$, so $?=\frac{b-a}{h}$. Thus your desired set is

$$\{a+hk:  0\leq  k \leq \frac{b-a}{h},  k \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$$

Te be clear this says the set of all $a+hk$ where $k$ takes values between $0$ and $\frac{b-a}{h}$ and $k$ must be an integer. That is the literal way to translate it, but a more eloquent phrasing would be "the set of all $a+hk$ where $k$ is an integer between $0$ and $\frac{b-a}{h}$.

Alternatively:

$$\{a+hk:  0\leq  k \leq N_a-1,  k \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$$

Since there are $N_a$ values in the vector and this makes $k$ range over $N_a$ different values.

Comment: This would give you $a, 2a, 3a, \ldots$ - I don't think that's what you want.  It should be  $\{a + hk: 0 \leq k \leq (b-a) / h\}$.

Comment: @jairtaylor Thanks! Messed that part up. It is corrected now.

Comment: is there any way I can introduce $N_a$ into this relation @Mark

Comment: $N_a -1= \lceil\frac{b-a}{h}\rceil $, since there are $\lceil\frac{b-a}{h}\rceil+1$ values $h$ takes. where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is the celing function (round up to the nearest integer equal to or larger than your input)

Comment: thanks @Mark really appreaciate your help.